# How can I make the target name of a Boost Build rule templated?

Tags: boost-build, bjam

I have a small Jamfile that I process with Boost Build that looks like this:

```
exe add-account    : add-account.cpp    ..//server-lib ../../shared//shared ;
exe add-deck       : add-deck.cpp       ..//server-lib ../../shared//shared ;
exe give-all-cards : give-all-cards.cpp ..//server-lib ../../shared//shared ;
exe give-card      : give-card.cpp      ..//server-lib ../../shared//shared ;

install . :
    add-account
    add-deck
    give-all-cards
    give-card
;
```

I feel like I should be able to do this with some sort of template. I've been looking around in the [Boost Build user manual](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/userman.pdf), but haven't found a language rule that will help me.

It's probably worth mentioning that I'm *aware* that more code is probably not the best solution here, but I'm still interested in if it can be done. It would at least be useful in cases where I want to compile an entire directory filled with single source-file programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to make this more concise. Just for illustration:

```
local exe-list = add-account add-deck give-all-cards give-card ;
for exe-file in $(exe-list)
{
    exe $(exe-file) : $(exe-file).cpp ..//server-lib ../../shared//shared ;
}

install . : $(exe-list) ;
```

You can also create a helper rule.

```
rule simple-exe ( name )
{
    exe $(name) : $(name).cpp ..//server-lib ../../shared//shared ;
}

local exe-list = add-account add-deck give-all-cards give-card ;
for exe-file in $(exe-list)
{
    simple-exe $(exe-file) ;
}

install . : $(exe-list) ;
```

Additionally - if same library dependencies are often used, they can be put into an `alias`

```
alias common : ..//server-lib ../../shared//shared ;

exe add-account    : add-account.cpp    common ;
exe add-deck       : add-deck.cpp       common ;
exe give-all-cards : give-all-cards.cpp common ;
exe give-card      : give-card.cpp      common ;
```

or in `project requirements`

```
project my-project : requirements
    <library>..//server-lib
    <library../../shared//shared
;

exe add-account    : add-account.cpp    ;
exe add-deck       : add-deck.cpp       ;
exe give-all-cards : give-all-cards.cpp ;
exe give-card      : give-card.cpp      ;
```

Some combination of these techniques should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for those examples! I have a really hard time with the documentation from b2 on occasion. I think I'll be able to simplify other aspects of my build files with those as well. Do you know if there's a way to do a `[ glob *.cpp ]` but return the list without the .cpp? That would simplify the first example further.

Comment: You can use MATCH builtin rule.

rule remove_ext ( file )
{
    return [ MATCH (.*)\\.[^.]* : $(file) ] ;
}